# Why to use memcached if Varnish is present

Tags: caching, nginx, memcached, varnish

I'm trying to build a webapp (with a lot of DYNAMIC content) and I need some cache system for speed up performance. At the moment I'm using nginx with load balancer.

I was looking at varnish as an http proxy for serve directly response from cache and avoiding send a request to nginx.

Later on I look at memcached, a nice key value pairs cache in RAM.

Now if I can cache all my request with varnish and set a little TTL for dynamic content that change frequently, why I should need a system as memcached for example?

I should use varnish just for static content and manage dynamic content with memcached?

Will be a bad practice to use varnish for all request and will be purge system(for dynamic content) an heavy tasks?

I'm a little confusing...Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Varnish + Memcached is a combination that makes perfect sense.

Normally, a web app has a guest and logged-in areas:

Varnish helps to completely bypass PHP engine execution by caching guest areas, allowing you to set high TTL there.
Example: articles content that is shown to a guest user.

Memcached is to help with *easing* the burden on PHP engine *when* the request is not satisfied by Varnish cache, i.e. for logged-in user.
Common things to store there include results of heavy SQL queries and other transient data that is costly to regenerate every time PHP runs.

Comment: I'm using java but I think what you said is equivalent for all language. So I shouldn't cache "userLoggedContent" in Varnish but just content that doesn't depend from logged user.

All other content that are user dependent can be cached through MemCached.

I'm right?

Comment: Basically, yes. You should understand that that is default Varnish behavior anyway. It will not cache a request that comes with cookies (logged in). Of course, you may wish to cache as much as possible with Varnish, even parts of pages for logged in users, for example sidebars output (which requires ESI to be enabled).